# MySQL Union and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, select, union-all

```
(SELECT * FROM Test1 WHERE (date >= '2012-06-28'AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0'))
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM Test2 WHERE (date >= '2012-06-28'AND date < '2012-06-30') AND (Avail > '0'));

MySQL results

Alpha   Price        date         Avail     description
A           165.00       2012-06-28     10  Something
D           200.00       2012-06-28     10  Something
D           200.00       2012-06-29     10  Something
```

Question:

```
Alpha = A --> date 2012-06-29 Avail = 0
```

How do I get MYSQL to ONLY get results for Alpha= D where date from 2012-06-28 to 2012-06-30 and Avail = 10. Alpha=A only has Avail for 2012-06-28

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but what's wrong with simply  putting `Alpha = 'D' AND Avail = '10'` in your query conditions?

Comment: or even `Alpha <> 'A' AND Avail > '0'`